# Probability of winning the league using Chernoff Bound

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

The soccer team "Team A" plays in a league of $n\geq 2$ teams and in each match Team A has probability $p=\frac{1}{10}$ of winning (there are no ties), independent of the last match. In this league, every team plays each of the other teams exactly once. The winner of the league is the team with more wins than any other team. I want to show that the probability of Team A winning the league is less than $(\frac{e}{5})^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

Since there are $n$ teams, each team will have $n-1$ games. Let $X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}$ be i.i.d. and Bernoulli distributed with $p=\frac{1}{10}$, therefore $X_i$ models whether Team A wins the $i$-th game ($X_i=1)$ or loses the $i$-th game ($X_i=0$).
Let $Y=\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}X_i$ be the number of games that Team A wins, therefore $Y$ is binomially distributed with $E[Y]=\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}E[X_i]=(n-1)E[X_1]=\frac{n-1}{10}$.
Team A can't win the league by winning half their games or less, because then at least one other team would win half their games or more, meaning, for it to be possible to win the league it would have to hold that $Y\gt \frac{n-1}{2}$. Let $\delta=4$, we obtain:
$$P(Y\gt \frac{n-1}{2})=P(Y\gt (1+4)\frac{n-1}{10})=P(Y\gt (1+\delta) E[Y])\leq \begin{pmatrix}\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\end{pmatrix}^{E[Y]}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{e^4}{5^{5}}\end{pmatrix}^{\frac{n-1}{10}}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{e^{4/5}}{5}\end{pmatrix}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} $$
In this inequality I  used that $Y$ is a sum of Bernoulli random variables in order to find a Chernoff bound. As $e^{4/5}\lt e$ this yields the desired result. Is this correct and are there better ways to solve this? Thanks for any feedback!